# Magento 1.9 show productData on catalog/product/list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, configurable-product

I am trying to display an if statement for products to show Item details if they exist. Otherwise display an attribute.

`<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('filter_metal'); ?>`

and it displays the attribute no problem as it exists.

But however I want to check for an item detail first (not an attribute) and then if that exists to display this instead.

On the product page I can get this product detail by;

`<?php echo $_product->getData('metal_type'); ?>`

but on the category list page it does not.. I am sure I am missing something.
Any assistance is great.

Here is what I was trying also to get if else;

`<?php if ($_product->getData('metal_type')): ?>
<?php echo $_product->getData('metal_type')?>
 <?php else:?>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('filter_metal'); ?>
<?php endif;?>`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom product attribute is always available on product detail page. In a category or other product list there are only the attributes available which have the flag `Use in product listing` set to `Yes`. Please check the settings of your attributes `filter_metal` and `metal_type` and correct the `Use in product listing` Flag.

After configuring the attributes correctly, please rebuild the product flat index and after that you should be able to use both attributes in product lists as you want.

I hope that helps.

Comment: 100%, thanks.. not sure how i missed this.